# Uploading pretty faces url-mapinng from database

Tags: prettyfaces

1) I need to create custom patterns from interface.
2) My pretty-config.xml is so large.

Is there a way to upload data to a pretty-config.xml from the database. Maybe there's another way to create patterns without having to edit the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need many custom mappings, consider using your own ConfigurationProvider, http://www.ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Extensions.html#ConfigurationProvider.

However, PrettyFaces is not really designed for this level of customization, so you might want to use Rewrite (what PrettyFaces is written on) directly:

http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/#section-5

Rewrite pretty much takes the ConfigurationProvider API from PrettyFaces and makes it a first-class API.

For example:
http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/examples/

~Lincoln

Comment: Thanks, Lincoln! Using the Rewrite annotations solved all my needs.